# Auto scroll not working in for loop in collection-view

Tags: swift

- Auto scroll not working in for loop in Swift
  I tried with timer using below code.
  Scrolling not working in second time. Working fine for first time.

```
private func setTimer() {
        self.timer?.invalidate()
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: timerInterval, repeats: true, block: { [weak self] (timer) in
            self?.scrollToNextIndex()
        })
    }
    @objc
    private func scrollToNextIndex() {
        currentIndex += 1
        if currentIndex >= viewModel.pages.count {
            currentIndex = 0
        }
        pageControl.currentPage = currentIndex
        self.managePageControlIndicator()

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let indexPath = IndexPath.init(row: self.currentIndex, section: 0)
            self.collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .left)

        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, there is a lot of context missing. have you tried to check for the value of self in the Timer block?

Since you are using weak reference to self, there is a possibility that self is nil hence scrollToNextIndex never called.

Also have you tried to use breakpoints in your code to spot what is call and what is not?

Comment: Instead of `selectItem` can you check with this `collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredVertically, animated: true)`

Comment: Thanks for answering. I did tried. Not updating selected item in n second time. Also added bread points and hit. But not scroll.